# Javascript XML place specific childs into variable

Tags: javascript, xml

Let's see i have the following xml:

```
<Response>
     <Text1></Text1>
     <Text2></Text2>
     <Text3></Text3>
</Response>
```

And I would like to put the Value of Text 1 into variable1, Text 2 into variable2 and Text 3 into variable 3. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked for an introductory tutorial for working with XML in JavaScript? Stackoverflow expects you to perform [a degree of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/19068) **before** you ask a question and to share the results of it in the question.

Comment: That’s not valid XML in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but I was not getting familiar with it

Comment: As @Xufox points out that's not valid XML. Additionally what code have you tried? If you haven't tried anything yet, check out [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_intro.asp), try some code and if you're still having trouble come back and post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

In my expection this code should work, but in fact it does not:

```
Variable1 =  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Text1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

Variable2 =  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Text2")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

Variable3 =  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Text3")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```